# How should I get user input in a model using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-interaction

I'm writing a program using c# and MVVM pattern. This program has an online connection, which requires a login. I've created a model class to handle the login process.

The login process goes like this: the login credentials (user name and password) are sent to a login page online, and on successful login, the server sends back login cookies. I store those cookies locally, and send them with each request from the server, until they expire.

I've created a GetLoginCookies() method in the model, which I'd like to be the only method to get the login cookies. The login in this method is as follows: get the stored login cookies, and verify them with the server. If there are no login cookies, or they are invalid (e.g. expired), the ask the user for new credentials, and send them to the server and get new login cookies.

The reason I want to handle everything in one method, is that I want to have one method that will always give me valid login cookies (or abort the operation) that I can use before any communication with the server.

My question is, what's the best way to implement the user input when using MVVM pattern?

Comment: If the user needs to enter something then use a text box.

Comment: I don't believe you fully grasp MVVM correctly.  The model (M) generally should merely contain _data_ and is not responsible for process logic.   I recommend this article - _[Implementing the Model-View-ViewModel Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx)_. Regards

Comment: @Micky Duncan: in that case, where does the logic goes? As far as I understood it, the view-model is used for view-specific logic. So where does generic logic goes?

Comment: @MickyDuncan: That's a pretty outdated  way of modeling the "Model", called anemic domain model. Many experts recommend the rich domain model where model that belongs to a model goes in the model class. Logic that do not belong to the model goes to the services and keep the service layer thin. Anyways, in this case the login mechanism goes to a service anyways as it's not model specific logic. But if you got a "Add Product to Order" functionality, it would clearly go to the Order Model class in rich domain model and not in a service

Comment: @Tseng Sounds like a _bloated model_ to me, but don't take my word for it, see how Blackbird Interactive used MVVM in their Unity 3D game https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q9aeNtKKXeo&index=17&list=PL74BsvJXcuTSB_tZABdURVsA-yDOJ4Oo9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a model you want a service. A service is just a utility class that can be injected into your ViewModels via dependency injection (you are using an IoC?)

Given logging in is just part of the system, and the cookie will be needed to perform other web calls I would create a service for the complete server interaction. That way the service can keep the cookie internally and your app doesn't have to worry about the details of login interaction.

For example

```
public class WebService {
    public void Login(string username, string password) { ... }
    public Data GetData() { ... }
    public void AddNewData(Data data) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't heard of IoC and dependency injection until now, so I have a lot to research now. And a service sounds just right for the function of this class. Is it "right" to have a service call a view, though? Because I still need to get user interaction if the stored cookies are invalid.

Comment: @o_z The service would be called by the ViewModel. So when you log in the service is called, and if the login fails the ViewModel updates the View to show this (by showing an error message for example).

Comment: thank you for the clarification. This still doesn't seem to solve my issue, though, as it doesn't match my desired user experience, which is: the user performs an operation that requires online connection (e.g. download item), the download method asks the GetLoginCookies for the stored cookies, and if they are invalid, only then it asks the user for credentials. I'd like to avoid forcing the user to login actively before it is absolutely necessary. So it's not the view-model that's calling the service, but rather the service that's calling the view. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: @o_z Ah I see. When performing an operation on the service the service should have some way to report back that a login is required. Then the ViewModel can decide to open a login view, or do something else (show an error dialog, silently fail).
The other option is to allow the service to open a login dialog. This is ok because services are implementation specific.

Comment: I now have to decide which of the 2 options is right for me in this case, but you've definitely set me on the right path. Thakns!